# Maven build OutOfMemoryError Chunck::new

Tags: java, exception, maven

I get an error every time I try and build a small project (our sdk).  I have set my MAVEN_OPTS to -Xms1024m -Xmx1536m and I have a 6-12 GB of swap on both of my hard drives (so 24 GB total).  I have 6 GB of physical ram on my box of which 4 GB is allocated... so I really don't think I should be getting this error!  When I build my main project I get an OutOfMemoryError as well, but when I build again it completes the build.  This project will not complete.  Any help?

OS Info:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 13:16:01-0600)
Java version: 1.6.0_22
Java home: C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

Stack Trace:

```
c:\dev\fi\fbisdk>mvn -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:131)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:118)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.init(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:83)
        at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:236)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip.addResources(Zip.java:804)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip.addResources(Zip.java:853)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip.executeMain(Zip.java:499)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip.execute(Zip.java:414)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        ... 23 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 38168 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.cpp:215), pid=6384, tid=600
#  Error: Chunk::new
#
# JRE version: 6.0_22-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# c:\dev\fi\fbisdk\hs_err_pid6384.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: can you post the parts of your pom.xml that have to do with calling antrun and building zip files?

Comment: Java need continous memory and on a 32-bit system this can be difficult to obtain when you try to get more than 1.3 GB.  I suggest you try 64-bit Java (on a 64-bit OS) and you shouldn't see this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the root of your problem, but -Xmx sets *max* memory. Set it higher. If it's set too low, you can get OutOfMemory exceptions. And keep Xms small as it may add to the problem.

Furthermore, take a peek at those hints, may prove useful:

http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/java/-Xmx-settings

Comment: Thanks.  I actually removed the max memory and just left the min.  It fixed the issue in the side project, but I still get the problem when I do a clean build on the main project the *first* time.  On the second attempt to build it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should debug it with the -X option, this should give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be executing an ant build from your maven build. If the ant build is forked, it doesn't take into account your MAVEN_OPTS. You should be able to pass similar memory settings to the ant build in order to provide it additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

Java needs continous memory and on a 32-bit system this can be difficult to obtain when you try to get more than 1.3 GB and you have many programs running already.  I suggest you try

- running maven before running anything else when your memory is mostly free,
- on 64-bit Java (on a 64-bit OS) and you shouldn't see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://practicalcloudcomputing.com/post/444939181/outofmemoryjnigzip.

The main point is "This OutOfMemoryError is not java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. The latter is thrown when the memory occupied by all of your reachable Java objects exceeds the max heap -Xmx setting"

Answer (score 0):

are you using the maven-antrun-plugin? then your error does NOT come from maven. therefore MAVEN_OPTS is useless. you have to set the argument maxmemory="1024m" (or whatever value suits your needs) in the java task of the antrun-plungin in the pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plung</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
    ...
      <configuration>
      ...
        <tasks>
        ...
          <java classname="..." fork="true" maxmemory="1024m" ...>
          ...
          </java>
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    ...
  </executions>
</plugin>
```